# How to run sh scripts on python?

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, window

Say I have a python program and I want to perform this

```
grep "username" accounts.txt
```

in 1 line

accounts.txt is in the same folder as my py file. I know in C there is some function like System(grep "username" accounts.txt) and would work wondering if there something like that in python. Normally python is too slow to read accounts.txt since its a large file. However in bash or linux its much faster, so wondering if I can use bash to find a username line then python prints it out.

If there is none, what would be an efficient way to integrate a large file of usernames that I can call on in my python code to print out the line associated with it.

Comment: For making system calls take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python#89243

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import os
os.system('grep username accounts.txt')
```

or

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('grep username accounts.txt', shell=True)
```

should work..I haven't used this alot but I know (for some reason) using subprocess is much better.

```
os.system('grep Hello test.txt')
```

output:    Hello World!

```
subprocess.call('grep Hello test.txt',shell=True)
```

output:    Hello World!

Comment: ''grep' is not recognized as an internal or external command,' no clue. I have bash it works fine there just not in python

Comment: see edit..make sure your quotations are correct..works for me

Answer (score 0):

Use the [commands](https://docs.python.org/2/library/commands.html) module or [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module to execute commands.

Note: Commands module has been removed from python3. So, if you're using python3 I would suggest to use the subprocess module where as python2 has both the modules.